# How to draw plots and have specific name for each plot

Tags: ggplot2, tidyverse

I draw plots stored in list `mp` , how to make `mp[["A"]]` plot title is `A_plot`? (And `mp[["B"]]` plot title is 'B_plot')
`title=paste0(names(.),'_plot')` can't get what i want

```
library(tidyverse)

test_data <- data.frame(
  category=c('A','A','A','B','B','B'),
  price=c(1,1,2,3,2,2),
  amount=c(1:6)
) %>% split(.$category)

mp <- map(test_data,~ ggplot(.,aes(x=price,y=amount))+
      geom_point()+labs(title=paste0(names(.),'_plot')))

mp[["A"]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `purrr::imap` you could do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mp <- imap(test_data, ~ ggplot(.x, aes(x = price, y = amount)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = paste0(.y, "_plot")))

mp[["A"]]
```

[image]